# Bash: How to send an openssl command and have the script output to stdin when it sees line X

Tags: bash, openssl

Is it possible to send an openssl command in a bash script, and then have the script wait for a prompt before outputting the correct text to stdin?

I want to be able to:

- Send an openssl command
- Wait for line X to appear
- Report a fault if line X does not appear
- Wait for line Y to appear
- Output to stdin
- More processing...

My current approach puts the openssl command in the background, pipes the output to a file (using tee, so I also see it in the terminal) and uses a while loop to continuously read the output.

My problem lies when I output to stdin. My script detects that line Y has appeared, but using `cat <<< "my_input"` does not work. I know that the openssl command is waiting for the input, because if I manually enter the command at that point, all is OK.

Any ideas what I'm missing? Or is there a better approach?

Note: I'm hoping for an approach which does not use a third party application, such as 'expect' mentioned below.

Comment: [Expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) was created to solve this type of problem. In addition to the original TCL library, there are versions for [Python](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/), [Perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Expect), [Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/expect/rdoc/IO.html), and many others.

Comment: I'm hoping to not have to use any external libraries. I've updated my question to include this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sticking to Bash: you need to call `openssl` in such a way that you have a file handle to its stdin in order to script sending data to it. For example, if you have Bash 4,

```
# Run openssl with stdin and stdout attached to pipes stored in ${OPENSSL[*]}
coproc OPENSSL {
    openssl ...
}

# Wait for a line to appear
while read -r -u ${OPENSSL[0]} line; do
    if [[ ${line} = X ]]; then
        break
    fi
done

# Send something to the input
echo 'hello, world!' >&${OPENSSL[1]}

# Close input
exec {OPENSSL[1]}>&-

# Forward everything from the output to our stdout
cat <&${OPENSSL[0]}
```

If you have an earlier version of Bash you will need to use named pipes order to attach to a process's stdin and stdout both.

If you only need to attach to stdin there are a few tricks: either redirect a subshell (which may be tricky to coordinate with reading data outside the subshell)

```
{
    echo 'hello, world! (from a subshell)'
} | openssl ... | tee ...
```

or use process substitution.

```
exec {OPENSSL}> >(openssl ... | tee ...)
echo 'hello, world!' >&${OPENSSL}
exec {OPENSSL}>&-
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! Using your first approach, I get the following error: `{OPENSSL[0]}: ambiguous redirect`. This points to the `cat <&{OPENSSL[0]}` line. Any ideas?

Comment: @mfisher91 Oops, that should be `cat <&${OPENSSL[0]}`, and a similar fix in a couple other places.

Comment: That's great. One more question; so, I want to put this in a loop, so my program will make the openssl connection & perform the task every X minutes. How do I kill the current co-process? I don't want to leave lots of co-processes open!

Comment: @mfisher91 The PID will be in `$OPENSSL_PID` because we named the array `${OPENSSL[*]}`, so you could kill it. But openssl should terminate naturally on its own after you close its stdin and fully read its stdout.